# Change behavior of space on external keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, external-keyboard, text-input

On my PC, I am using [TouchCursor](http://touchcursor.sourceforge.net/), so that I can control the text cursor using key combinations such as:

- **SPACE+I/J/K/L**: up/left/down/right
- **SPACE+H/N**: page up/down

That way, and when using a keyboard with a TrackPoint, everything is reachable from the home row, and I don't need to move hands. TouchCursor reconfigures the space key:

- to act as a modifier key when pressed together with **I/J/K/L/H/N/...**, and
- to act as space, when pressed and released.

Can I get the same functionality with an *external keyboard* connected to a modern Android device?

Answer (score 1):

I have done extensive research talking to developers who make applications for Android and the PageDown & PageUp do not exist in Android unless the application chooses to implement this(which is quite rare).  The PgDn key doesn't even work on [Chromebook with Android apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/168500/page-down-and-page-up-dont-work/190755#190755).  The only application that I know of that implements the PageDown key at all are web browsers like Chrome.  I also use a pointing stick so I understand your frustration and or desire to have a feature like this.  My best advice would be to either VPN/VNC into another computer which has this implemented or use SSH/MOSH to have such feature at least at the terminal.