# Page Down and Page Up Don't Work

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, external-keyboard

So I have an external keyboard plugged into my android device that has Page Down and Page Up keys but they don't work in anything but I think the Chrome web browser.

Is there a fix for this?

This is related but doesn't tackle the same issue [Page up and page down in web pages and elsewhere](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56561/page-up-and-page-down-in-web-pages-and-elsewhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have experimented with this a lot and basically have concluded that Android devices were not intended to be operated this way.

Even [Chromebook's running Android apps](https://superuser.com/questions/1245981/does-the-page-down-key-work-in-android-apps-running-on-chrome-os) don't support the PageDown key.